# trouble in Codeigniter taking data from one db table and creating a entry in another with it

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, xampp

I am trying to take info from a MySQL 5.4 table create a entry into another table, then delete the prior entry. I cant see what i am doing wrong.

I am running an Acer Aspire 5920,

Ubuntu 12.04,

Xampp 1.8.1,

Codeigniter 2.1.3

MySQL 5.4

this is a screenshot of the errors:

[image: Screen shot of error messages]

this is a screenshot of the original entry:

[image]

this is a screenshot of the created entry:

[image: pic of created data base entry]

```
public function add_user($key){

    $this->db->where('key', $key);

    $temp_user = $this->db->get('temp_users');

    if($temp_user){

        $row = $temp_user->row();

        $data = array(
                'email' => $row-email,
                'password' => $row->password
            );

        $did_add = $this->db->insert('users', $data);

    }

    if($did_add){

        $this->db->where('key', $key);
        $this->db->delete('temp_users', $key);



    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $data = array(
                'email' => $row-email,
                'password' => $row->password
            );
```

Should be

```
 $data = array(
                'email' => $row->email,
                'password' => $row->password
            );
```

Missing ">" in "$ row-email"